# Работа с AJAX и JSON

Tags: ajax, json

Здравствуйте. Есть некоторые вопросы в плане работы с AJAX и JSON. Хочется сделать всё грамотно, поэтому выясняю тонкости работы.

У меня есть страницы Новостей. Шапка, футер и комментарии неизмЕнны. Нужно подгружать только сами новости (текст, фотогалерею и основное большое фото).
Правильно ли будет использовать AJAX и JSON для подгрузки новостного блока? Чтобы не сама страница полностью обновлялась,  а только ее один контент?

P.S. Еще не понятен сам процесс. Говорится, что запрос направляется на сервер. На какой собственно сервер? Я так понимаю, что запрос направляется на JSON файл. Он и является сервером?

[image: Фото]

Comment: в плане сео - не очень, а вот в плане удобства для пользователя - очень =)

Comment: да с SEO будет полная лажа, а для текстовых ресурсов это архи-важно. Или делать 2 версии сайта - html-ую для роботов, и динамическую для людей

Comment: "Хочется сделать всё грамотно ... JSON файл ... является сервером?" - "Чтение - вот лучшее учение." Советский букварь.